# Testing value of each related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does Ruby (or Rails) provide an easy way to accomplish the following:

```
if @author.articles.each(:published == true)
  puts "all articles of this author are published"
end
```

I think the example speaks for itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone will find something better, but here are some things that would work:

```
unless @author.articles.map{|a| a.published == true}.include?(false)
  puts "all articles of this author are published"
end
```

or...

```
if @author.articles.select{|a| !a.published}.size == 0
  puts "all articles of this author are published"
end
```

or...

```
if @author.articles.detect{|a| !a.published}.nil?
  puts "all articles of this author are published"
end
```

My preference goes for the last one.

Comment: Thanks! I also like the 'detect' one, gives some indication of what i'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't have to load the articles ...

```
if @author.articles.count == @author.articles.count(:conditions => { :published => true })
 puts "..."
end
```

Comment: That would be even easier. But in my case its not a DB-field, but a custom generated attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is yet another one:

> puts "all #{@author.name}'s articles are published" if @author.articles.all?(&:published?)